Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks. Read remote repositories from pom.xml file
We are tring to migrate to "Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks" from "Maven Ant Tasks".
The "Maven Ant Tasks" reads remote repositories definitions from the pom.xml
<artifact:dependencies filesetid="maven.classpath" usescope="compile">
    <pom file="../pom.xml"/>
</artifact:dependencies>

We observe that "Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks" completely ignores <repositories/> section of the pom.xml
Is it a chance that "Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks" could read <repositories/> section from the pom.xml?
The only thing that I found is to explicitly repeat them ...
<resolver:pom file="../pom.xml" id="pom"/>
        
<resolver:resolve>
    <dependencies pomRef="pom"/>
    <remoterepos>
        <remoterepo id="central" url="https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"/>
        <remoterepo id="id1" url="https://releases.xyz.com/java/repo"/>
    </remoterepos>
    <path refid="maven.classpath" classpath="compile"/>
</resolver:resolve>

